# How to launch a new activity from an image button without launching a new layout?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The main activity class file contains an image button that is designed to launch another activity within the same layout that is already in use.

The other activity is a separate class file and the image button in the main activity class contains an intent to launch that activity.

I want to launch the activity without altering the current activity or creating a new one. The activity is a strobe runner. It doesn't need a separate layout.

What I've done:

- Declared the other activity in the android manifest.
- Declared the launch intent filters as main and launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to create a new fragment within the MainActivity. Covert your second activity code into fragment code.

Here's more:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html